# Monster of an inner join...multi part ... could not be bound?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this T-SQL Server 2008 query:

```
SELECT users.user_id,
       course_main.course_name,
       course_main.course_id
FROM   users,
       course_main
       INNER JOIN course_application
         ON users.pk1 /*(error #1)*/ = course_application.pk1
       INNER JOIN course_main /*(error #2)*/
         ON course_application.crsmain_pk1 = course_main.pk1
       INNER JOIN course_users
         ON users.pk1 /*(error #3)*/ = course_users.users_pk1
            AND course_main.pk1 = course_users.crsmain_pk1
            AND course_main.pk1 = course_users.child_crsmain_pk1
WHERE  course_users.role = 'P'
       AND ( ( course_main.course_id ) LIKE '%FA2013'
             AND ( course_application.application ) = 'alrn-AtomicLearning_tool' )
       AND ( ( ( course_application.enable_ind ) = 'Y'
                OR ( course_application.visible_ind ) = 'N' )
              OR ( ( course_application.enable_ind ) = 'N'
                    OR ( course_application.visible_ind ) = 'Y' ) )
```

And all of the nested joins are giving me a headache. I expected SQL Server 2008 with the query designer to be able to put in at least aliases, but I guess I was wrong.

When I am in the editor, I am getting an error for `users.pk1` in the first join that says

> The multi-part identifier "users.pk1" could not be bound

I also get this error:

> The objects "course_main" and "course_main" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them

I know vaguely about aliases, and know how to put them into SQL for very, very basic tasks, but I am just going to confuse myself to the point of no return. I've read all I could about aliases but just don't know where to properly use them in a join this complex. Please help!

Thank you

edit: I'm not really sure how to state what my intent is. Basically I'm trying to get the 3 columns out of all of the tables I'm selecting from. To get the correct data the keys and all that have to match between the tables. In SQL Server 2008 I selected the tables that all have relationships. I've run queries before where all I was selecting from was the course_main and course_application table. Since those have a direct relationship a single join was all that was needed to make that happen. Adding in these 2 extra tables(users and course_users to define which users match up as a specific role in our database against the keys in the other tables)made it a lot more complicated.

These are the schemas for the four tables:

http://pastebin.com/AJuiGv9s

Comment: You are mixing JOIN types which is causing the problem. Stick with using ANSI sql (INNER JOIN, etc) and remove the `, course_main`.

Comment: Why are you using one implicit join mixed in with all the proper ones?

Comment: Can you please provide the list of full table names for the tables that you are trying to pull from? It appears from the query that you are trying to pull from a table named simply "users", but the first error implies that there is no "users" table (or that it does not have a pk1 field).

Comment: I need to pull from users and course_main. Just selecting from users won't return all of the data, right? I'm not explicitly doing anything. I went into the DB in Sql Server 2008 management studio and selected the tables I wanted to be able to use conditions in and select data from based on the primary keys matching.

Here is a link to a page from the schema for the database, it does have a users table and definitely has a pk1 key that is often used as a foreign key in other tables

http://library.blackboard.com/ref/8c156cbc-7160-4e64-9f00-f06ea67a0fe0/tables/as_core/users.html

Comment: And please, a 5-table join is nothing but a monster.

Comment: To a newb it's a lot lol.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to always use aliases for your tables, like this

```
select
   u.user_id,
   cm.course_name,
   cm.course_id
from users as u
   cross join course_main as cm
   inner join course_application as ca on u.pk1 /*(error #1)*/ = ca.pk1
   inner join course_main as cm2/*(error #2)*/ on ca.crsmain_pk1 = cm.pk1
   inner join course_users as cu on u.pk1 /*(error #3)*/ = cu.users_pk1
....
```

You are also mixing join styles - I suggest to use actual join instead of writing `from users, course_main`

I'm sure that when you rewrite your query with aliases it'll be easier to find a mistake

Comment: aliasing is not the issue here.

Comment: Your sample query with the aliases will not work because of the mixed JOINs.

Comment: @bluefeet yes, my fault :) I'm always writing ANSI style joins and never tried to mix two styles, and not ansi joins are ugly.

Comment: @RomanPekar To make it cleaner, you might want to use CROSS JOIN

Comment: @bluefeet changed an answer. Actually, I also really don't like that all capitals style of writing queries :)

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, your issue is because of the mixed join types. I think this will work for you.

You were also joining in `course_main` twice, and I think that you can condense that into one join on the `course_application` table.

```
SELECT 
     u.user_id
    ,cm.course_name
    ,cm.course_id
FROM users AS u
CROSS JOIN course_main AS cm
JOIN course_application AS ca
  ON u.pk1 = ca.pk1
 AND ca.crsmain_pk1 = cm.pk1
JOIN course_u AS cu
  ON u.pk1 = cu.u_pk1
 AND cm.pk1 = cu.crsmain_pk1
 AND cm.pk1 = cu.child_crsmain_pk1
WHERE cu.role = 'P'
  AND cm.course_id LIKE '%FA2013'
  AND ca.application = 'alrn-AtomicLearning_tool' 

  AND (( 
        ca.enable_ind  = 'Y'
     OR ca.visible_ind = 'N' 
    ) OR (
        ca.enable_ind  = 'N'
     OR ca.visible_ind = 'Y' 
    ))
```

I'm thinking that instead of a cross-join between `users` and `course_application` (do you really want a row for each combination of user and application in your database?), you probably want to introduce a regular `INNER JOIN` and join on some key.

Comment: Would it help a lot more if I linked to the table's schemas? That code does work but it doesn't return any results.

I wrote this to get which users are teaching which courses, and I needed to take it a step further with my other query above, selecting the courses, the instructors, and the users that meet the certain application criteria.

http://pastebin.com/YBGcdAbx

Comment: He probably need joining that table twice.

Comment: @user1275954: The way you joined `users` to `course_main` through `course_users` in the Pastebin example made more sense to me. Why don't you try building the entire thing around that 3-table join?

Comment: I think I did a four table join that should work. Tell me what you think!

http://pastebin.com/vSVVvyqK

Comment: @user1275954: Seems fine but whether it would return the correct results, you are in a better position to tell. However, it doesn't use the `course_users.child_crsmain_pk1` column in any way, as your original query did, which makes your revised version appear different (in intent) from the original.

Comment: that course_users.child join/column always pops up whenever you use the query designer and let sql server fill out some of the pre code for you involving the multiple inner joins you see way above. sorry for all of the confusion. the next time I face an issue i'll be a lot more thorough in my intent.

Answer (score 0):

Re-wrote query based on all of the advice given.

```
use BBLEARN
SELECT u.user_id,
    cm.course_name,
    cm.course_id
FROM users as u
join course_users cu on u.pk1 = cu.users_pk1
join course_main cm on cu.crsmain_pk1=cm.pk1
join course_application ca on cm.pk1 = ca.crsmain_pk1

WHERE cu.role='P'
AND
((cm.course_id) LIKE '%FA2013' AND (ca.application) = 'alrn-AtomicLearning_tool')
AND (((ca.enable_ind) = 'Y' OR (ca.visible_ind) = 'N')
OR ((ca.enable_ind) = 'N' OR (ca.visible_ind) = 'Y'))
```

http://pastebin.com/vSVVvyqK